# Converting infix notation expression to postfix notation

Tags: c++, stack, notation, infix-notation

I'm doing an assignment for my Data Structures course where I have to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression. I'm almost done with it but I keep getting an error when I try entering something like a+b+c

It can handle a+b and a+b*c just fine.

I'm really not sure what's wrong with it. If someone could point me in a direction or see the problem with my code, I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std; 

//checks priority of operators.
int priority(char e){
    int pri = 0; 

    if(e == '*' || e == '/' || e == '%'){
        pri = 2; 
    }else{
        if(e == '+' || e == '-'){
            pri = 1; 
        }
    }
    return pri; 
}

void main(){
    cout << "This program will convert an infix expression to a postfix expression." << endl; 
    cout << "Please enter your expression without any spaces." << endl; 

    stack<char> charStack; 

    char input[100]; 
    char output[100];
    char n1; 

    char *o; 
    o = &output[0]; 

    cin >> input; 

    int n = 0; 
    while(input[n] != 0){

        if(isdigit(input[n])  || isalpha(input[n])){
            *o = input[n]; 
            n++; 
            o++; 
        }

        if(input[n] == '('){
            charStack.push(input[n]); 
            n++;
        }

        if(input[n] == ')'){
            n1 = charStack.top(); 
            charStack.pop(); 
            while(n1 != '('){
                *o = n1; 
                o++; 
                n1 = charStack.top(); 
                charStack.pop(); 
            }
            n++; 
        }

        if(input[n] == '+' || input[n] == '-' || input[n] == '*' || input[n] == '/' || input[n] == '%'){
            if(charStack.empty() == true){
                charStack.push(input[n]);
            }else{
                n1 = charStack.top(); 
                charStack.pop(); 
                while(priority(n1) >= priority(input[n])){
                    *o = n1; 
                    o++;
                    n1 = charStack.top(); 
                    charStack.pop(); 
                }
                charStack.push(n1); 
                charStack.push(input[n]); 
            }
            n++; 
        }
    }
    while(!charStack.empty()){
        *o = charStack.top(); 
        o++; 
        charStack.pop(); 
    }
    *o = '\0'; 

    cout << output << endl; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check whether the stack is empty before popping an element in the code for operators. That's part of the problem.

By the way, it should be `int main()` instead of `void`, and you don't need to compare things with `true`: `charStack.empty() == true` is the same as `charStack.empty()`.

Answer (score 1):

See my comments inline.

```
// You can empty the stack here.
charStack.pop(); 

while(priority(n1) >= priority(input[n])){
    ...

    // BUG: This line will crash if the stack is empty.
    // You need to check for an empty stack.
    n1 = charStack.top();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :D Same as the person above, but I appreciate it.